# When can safely access mutex protected variable without locking?

Tags: concurrency, go, synchronization, race-condition

A common pattern of storing config in my code is a "map[string]interface{}" protected by RWMutex, but usually after app initiated (could be triggered in multiple go-routine), the map becomes totally readonly. So I have a feeling that from some point of time on, the RWMutex on read should be unnecessary.

An example of this config map is at 
http://play.golang.org/p/tkbj9DBok_

One fact that brought me to think of this is in some of production code it actually doing this way of unprotected access of shared object (though it's mostly readonly after it's init'ed), I understand normal way of using RWMutex to protect, but interesting part is this malformed code haven't run into problem in past months.

Is that true that after some accurate "time point" that writes are flushed from cache into memory and with a guarantee of no more writes needed, reads can actually go without RWMutex.RLock? If YES, when is the time point or how to setup the conditions before lockless access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as no one is modifying the map, it should be safe for multiple threads to read it at once.  Unfortunately, without any locking you'll have no way to make sure no one else is reading the map when you want to update it.

So one solution is to never update the map, but instead replace it atomically.  The [read-copy-update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) algorithm could be used here.  Rather than directly accessing the map, so you need to dereference the pointer to access the map.  To update it, you can do the following:

1. acquire an "update lock" mutex.
2. make a copy of the map.  You want to copy all keys/values manually: simple assignment won't work because maps are reference types.
3. make your changes to the copy of the map.
4. use `StorePointer` from the `sync/atomic` package to atomically update the pointer to the live map to point to your new map.
5. release the mutex.

Everything that runs before the atomic update in (4) will see the old map, and everything after will see the new map.  At no point will those goroutines be reading from a map that is being written to, so there is no need for an `RWMutex`.

Comment: I believe you will have to use `LoadPointer` to read from a map in this case.

Comment: but one thing I still feel not sure is the possible overhead comparison between RWMutex.RLock (an atomic add for pure read) and an atomic LoadPointer. I know it's very trivial in most system but not sure if anyway to fully get rid of them.

Comment: @kostya: if we were going fully lock free, then `LoadPointer` would be necessary, yes.  With a mutex protecting updates, it shouldn't be necessary.  The `StorePointer` is for the benefit of the readers.

Comment: @JasonXu: acquiring the read lock is cheap provided no one has the write lock.  The benefit of RCU is that readers aren't blocked at all by writes.  Of course, this is only appropriate if you're okay with readers seeing the old value before the update completes.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, would you mind to explain why is that?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, race detector reports a data race in the following program http://play.golang.org/p/iHU2JCgrFl, note that when using LoadInt32 there is no data race

Comment: @kostya: there is a race in the sense that the reader will either see the old or new version of the pointer, but they will never see an intermediate version of the map.  If you need more guarantees than  that, then perhaps the RWLock is more appropriate.

Comment: At the same time there are no guarantees in the Go spec that StorePointer(&x) happens before reading from x. Correct me if I am wrong but I believe it means that goroutine reading from x can see intermediate version of the map. Also (though very unlikely) it is possible that a reading goroutine will never see an updated value (e.g. when map pointer is cached in a register or processor cache).

Comment: Note that the `sync/atomic` package provides [`atomic.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value) which can be easier/better than `atomic.StorePointer` depending on what you're doing (e.g. the documentation includes an [example showing a safe rarely modified map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#example_Value_readMostly) via copy on write).

Comment: @kostya: if the reader dereferences `x` before the `StorePointer` call, then it will access the old map.  There is no way the reader could access an intermediate version of the map because it has no way of knowing where it is stored until after the pointer update.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, what if a processor or a compiler reorders StorePointer call and operations before it? Or StorePointer value becomes visible to a reader thread, but memory effects from map assignment still haven't been flushed to the main memory from a processor cache?

Answer (score 1):

`RLock` and `RUnlock` are very fast operations. If there are no writers they are essentially lockless and take just 1 atomic operation each (http://golang.org/src/sync/rwmutex.go?h=RLock#L29). So unless your application performs poorly because reading configuration is slow I would suggest to use `RWLock`.

Note, that my initial answer was a proposal to implement `Freeze()` operation for `Register` but later I realized that the correct implementation won't be any faster than using RWLock.

Comment: Thanks for fast comment. The point is the initiation (write) could be concurrent and there's no good place to do a "freeze". but eventually the write would be done and no more. Initially I'm thinking of proactively waiting 10 second to guarantee writes are over and flushed to memory. however I'd like to see if I missed something.

Comment: I've just realized that my suggested solution is wrong (because readonly field is read without lock). This is just proves that using locks is the best way to make it correct.

Comment: Rules that describe when write to variable becomes visible can be found here: http://golang.org/ref/mem